# Controlling NHibernate entity Eagerloading

Tags: c#, hibernate, nhibernate, asp.net-web-api, orm

I'm relatively new to NHibernate. I'm working on a web app in which i need to detach the entity from Hibernate session and pass it to UI for changes. I'm using **NHibernateUtil.Initialize** for eager loading of the entity. The problem i'm facing is the entity has a lot of collections and some collections have even child collections, so when i'm using **NHibernateUtil.Initialize** it is eager loading all the collections, which in turn increasing my JSON data that i pass to UI layer.I'm using ASP.NET Webapi in the service layer.  Is there a way to control the eager loading to only particular collections that i need in the entity . Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: I would say, that solution is not on Data layer. Not inside of NHibernate, not by using eager loading. Solution should be on a service layer. Imlement Custom Resolvers, inject them into JSON serializer settings. These should be able to drive how deep your entity should be loaded and converted into JSON. Or - use DTO. Thes should be filled by some mapper (acts similar to Resolver in fact). But do not place that requirement on NHiberante. It is not a tool for JSON conversions

Comment: What did you try? can you post some code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your mapping you can specify the default behaviour for lazy loading of collections and references. How are you creating you mappings? You can override the default by specifying a fetch strategy in individual queries. What module are you using for your query (QueryOver, Linq etc.)? My preference is to always set the default to lazy load and then eager fetch as required.

Also, my preference is to not pass the entity directly to the UI layer but to create a ViewModel in the Controller.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm using HQL in data layer for for hydrating the entities. As of now i've created few DTO's , which I'm gonna push to UI. But I feel I'll have few issues with this approach since my DTO is  is independent of entity , I guess I've to map it back to entity after updates/deletes .. I'm not sure if my approach is the right one

Comment: Yes, that's right you need to map it back. The big downside of using DTOs is you end up with a lot of duplicated code.